# Have an argument of type object, whose property names/values vary. Need to send prop name/values through URL in GET request

Tags: javascript

I have a route on my express api which queries the db with Sequelize like so:

```
Islands.findAll({
    where: {
        region: 'pacific'
},
    include: {
        model: BonoboIslands,
        include: [ Bonobos ]
    }
}).then(function(result){
    res.send(result);
});
```

Now, the where clause will be changing depending on the specifications of the user - it could be as general as the pacific as is here, or maybe the user is interested in one particular island, and so the where clause would reflect that. In that case it would be `where: { island: 'cliffburger' }`

I'd like to pass this information through the url like `/bonoboLibrary/:locationParam/:locationValue`, but how do I encode the object when I get it from `req.params.locationParam` and `req.params.locationValue` so I wind up with an object like this: `{ locationParam : "locationValue" }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, you can use array notation to create an object's property with a dynamic name:

```
var whereClause = {};
whereClause[req.params.locationParam] = req.params.locationValue;
// for /bonoboLibrary/island/cliffburger
// whereClause is { island: 'cliffburger' }

Islands.findAll({
    where: whereClause,
    // ....
});
```